# Accessing Variable from Controller in Another Apex Class

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a variable, that is set in a method of an Apex class that is set as the controller of a custom VF page:

```
public without sharing class HomeController{
  public HomeController(){
    init();
  }
  public List<People__c> people;
  public void init(){
    people = [my soql]
  }
}
```

I now want to access this people variable in another Apex class - caveat being that this Apex class is the controller for a VF Component that is loaded through the Template of the same VF page. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why not just pass it through using `<apex:attribute>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when I have data I've already spent governors acquiring, I pass it through using the `<apex:attribute>` [tag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_attribute.htm) in my component. On the receiving end, it would look like:

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="people" type="People__c[]" description="..." />
</apex:component>
```

Then, on the page itself:

```
<c:myComponent people="{!people}" />
```

You can get fancier than that, but I've never had a need to do so.

Comment: I was about to get fancier than that, but then I'd just be duplicating effort.